# Loading tensorflow-gpu in python seems to force my windows computer to restart after putting it to sleep

Tags: tensorflow

Running Windows 10 on my laptop (with a compatible GPU) and just started using tensorflow-gpu 2 days ago. Every time I close the lid to put the laptop to sleep, it restarts when I wake it up. This never happened when I was just running normal tensorflow. I thought I'd see here if this is normal or known before running it up the flagpole on their git repo.